# Working with lists: Is it possible to make this piece of code faster?

Tags: python, list

Consider the following question:

We have a (big) list, say `a`, of non-zero integers and we want to find the maximum of **all** summations from the 1st element to the i-th element of the list for `0 <= i < len(a)`. To do this, I wrote my code as follows:

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 7, 8, -9, 10, -11]
groups = (group for key, group in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: x > 0)) # Gathering consecutive integers of the same sign suffices and make the code faster.
summations = [sum(group) for group in groups]
b = []
for i in range(len(summations)):
    b.append(sum(summations[ :i + 1]))
print(max(b))
```

Now, my question is: I want to do this faster. Is there a way? For example, I tried to keep the summation as a `generator` but, I couldn't loop over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at `itertools.accumulate()`?

```
import itertools

a = [1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 7, 8, -9, 10, -11]

print(max(itertools.accumulate(a)))
```